# Completely delete the first OS in dual boot

Tags: multi-boot

The first os of my laptop is windows 10 followed by 7. I want to delete the first operating system. Can U help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into file explorer, and right-click on "this pc". You must do this in the 
Windows 7 OS, or it might not work. Click manage. Computer management will pop up. In the sidebar, go to Storage>disk management. (Note: this might take a while to load!) Right-click on the partition labeled Windows, (Make sure it is the Windows 10 partition!) and press "Delete Volume." It will delete the partition. It will turn into a black bar labeled Unallocated space. If you want to add this extra space back to your windows 7 partition, then right click on your win 7 partition and press extend volume to add the unallocated space.

Comment: But there is a drive named "System Reserved" and that is used to boot operating systems but I think it shouldn't show up in File Explorer. How to hide it?